# Simplification of the exponential integral to a closed form

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Can the following integral be simplified to a closed form expression?

$$f = e^{yE}\int_{-z}^{z} \frac{e^{\Gamma \beta}}{\beta A + E} \,d\beta - e^{-yE}\int_{-z}^{z} \frac{e^{\xi \beta}}{\beta A + E}\, d\beta$$

I have tried solving the problem and I am getting solution in term of the exponential integral: $\int e^t/t\,dt = \operatorname{Ei}(t)$. Further, I tried approximating the exponential integral using the Taylor series expansion of $e^t/t$. However, the solution is quite cumbersome.

Is there a solution to the original integration or an approximation without using the $\operatorname{Ei}(t)$?

Comment: Are you supposed to know about exponential integrals ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for the solution you have provided below. I was looking for a closed form solution without the exponential integrals. Or any approximation of closed of exponential integrals.

Comment: Have a look to my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Consider
$$I=\int \frac {e^{ax}} {bx+c}\,dx$$
Let $$bx+c=t\implies x=\frac{t-c}{b}\implies dx=\frac{dt}{b}$$ which makes
$$I=\frac{e^{-\frac{a c}{b}}}{b}\int \frac{e^{\frac{a t}{b}}}{t}\,dt$$ Make now $\frac{a t}{b}=y$ to end with something like
$$\int \frac {e^y} y \,dy=\text{Ei}(y)$$ Back to $x$, 
$$I=\frac{e^{-\frac{a c}{b}} }{b}\,\text{Ei}\left(\frac{a c}{b}+a x\right)$$

**Edit**

In terms of approximation, for large values of $y$, you could use
$$\text{Ei}(y)=\frac{e^y}y\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {n!}{y^n}$$ and truncate it.

Similarly, for small values of $y$,
$$\text{Ei}(y)=\gamma+\log(y)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {y^n} {n \,n!}$$ which, I suppose, is what you used

Comment: By "and truncate it", do you mean truncate the summation?  For example, are you simply saying that one should just choose a max value of $n$ to sum over? As a native English speaker, the subject of "truncate" is not clear.

Comment: @whn. Yes. Make that a Taylor series to $O(y^p)$ summing from $n=1$ to $n=p-1$.

Comment: How do I figure out when to stop on the divergent series (large value approximation)?  If max n is too high  you'll overshoot the value.

Comment: @whn. For large or small values of $y$ ?

Comment: large values of $y$, the first one after **Edit**.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out.  The divergent series: $$\text{Ei}(y)=\frac{e^y}y\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {n!}{y^n}$$ follows a curve with the difference from value y based on N iterations (checked in code, and shown on wikipedia).  I can figure out when the difference switches from getting smaller to getting larger, and that allows me to figure out the most "optimal" place to stop iterating automatically. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20asymptotic%20expansion,the%20function%20tends%20towards%20a